# How to change metadata company_name using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, ffprobe

According to the documentation, to change the metadata,we have to use -metadata option and provide key/value pair of the metadata that we want to add/change:

```
ffmpeg -i in.avi -metadata title="my title" out.flv
```

So, I tried doing:

```
ffmpeg -i in.avi -metadata company_name="My Company" out.flv
```

Now, when I print out the metadata using ffprobe:

```
Metadata:
    uid             : adab4424-2f25-4dc7-92ff-29bd000c0000
    generation_uid  : adab4424-2f25-4dc7-92ff-29bd000c0001
    company_name    : FFmpeg
```

How do I change the metadata company_name?

EDIT:

log after running the ffmpeg command

```
ffmpeg -i in.avi -metadata company_name="My Company" out.flv
ffmpeg version 3.4.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.18.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.1 : stereo
Input #0, mxf, from 'rep12.mxf':
  Metadata:
    uid             : adab4424-2f25-4dc7-92ff-29bd000c0000
    generation_uid  : adab4424-2f25-4dc7-92ff-29bd000c0001
    company_name    : FFmpeg
    product_name    : OP1a Muxer
    product_version : 57.83.100
    product_uid     : adab4424-2f25-4dc7-92ff-29bd000c0002
    modification_date: 0-01-02T00:00:00.000000Z
    material_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010D001343BF7652947134C343BF760052947134C34300
    timecode        : 00:00:00:00
  Duration: 00:00:30.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3027 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg2video (4:2:2), yuv422p(tv, progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 29.97 tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010D001343BF7652947134C343BF760052947134C34301
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s16le, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010D001343BF7652947134C343BF760052947134C34301
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mpeg2video (native) -> mpeg2video (native))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (pcm_s16le (native) -> pcm_s16le (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, mxf, to 'out.mxf':
  Metadata:
    uid             : adab4424-2f25-4dc7-92ff-29bd000c0000
    generation_uid  : adab4424-2f25-4dc7-92ff-29bd000c0001
    timecode        : 00:00:00:00
    product_name    : OP1a Muxer
    product_version : 57.83.100
    product_uid     : adab4424-2f25-4dc7-92ff-29bd000c0002
    modification_date: 0-01-02T00:00:00.000000Z
    material_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010D001343BF7652947134C343BF760052947134C34300
    company_name    : Pushp
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg2video (4:2:2), yuv422p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbn, 29.97 tbc
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010D001343BF7652947134C343BF760052947134C34301
      encoder         : Lavc57.107.100 mpeg2video
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/200000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s16le, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s
    Metadata:
      file_package_umid: 0x060A2B340101010501010D001343BF7652947134C343BF760052947134C34301
      encoder         : Lavc57.107.100 pcm_s16le
frame=  900 fps=407 q=24.8 Lsize=   11047kB time=00:00:30.03 bitrate=3013.6kbits/s speed=13.6x    
video:4456kB audio:5631kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 9.519076%
```

Comment: Works here. Share full log.

Comment: Hey @Gyan the log is too large to paste here! So I have edited the question description and added the log!